# How to return a row from xlsx file based on items in a list

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of phrases that I want to use to retrieve specific rows/cells form an xlsx file. The list values are always spelled exactly how the English column on the database is.

[image: Excel]

I need each sentence - in different language, to be put into their own list that can be outputted into a different excel file looking like this:
[image: Output]

```py
# importing openpyxl module
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
# Give the location of the file
path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/ExcelTest.xlsx"

# To open the workbook
# workbook object is created
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)

# Get workbook active sheet object
# from the active attribute
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
max_col = sheet_obj.max_column
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row
eng = []
fre = []
ger = []
spa = []
ita = []
list = ['Hello', 'I Love', 'Python']

for row in sheet_obj:
    for a in list:
        for cell in row:
                if cell.value == a:
                    #print('Row:', cell.row , 'Column:', cell.column, 'Value:', cell.value)
                    for i in range(1, 5):
                        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = cell.row, column = i)
                        print(cell_obj.value, end= ' ')
                        eng.append(cell_obj.value)
                break
print (eng)
```

Now the result i get from the code is partly correct - except the whole thing (every sentence from different languages is put into one list instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this

```
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/ExcelTest.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(path)

languages = ['English', 'French', 'German', 'Spanish', 'Italian']
for language in languages:
    print(df[language].values)
```

Comment: It works great! Although for some reason I am getting a weird output. For example the English is: ['Hello' 'I Love' 'Python' nan nan nan 'Hello I love Python']

Comment: @babis95 You probably have empty cells in the lines under the text. Delete those rows from the excel file.

Comment: This fixed it. I think however if phrased the original question wrong. I am working on a simple translation program. Where user will type in an English phrase into a text box: e.g. 'Hello'. - This phrase is then stored in a list. This should then iterate through the excel database and return the row where English is (Hello) and all other languages on this row (Places every different language into their own list). Your program goes through everything in the file.

Comment: @babis95 You can just set `language` variable to whatever you want. You don't have to use loop.